# Taking properties from Maven settings.xml file to application context

Tags: maven, properties, settings

There are nice SO [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107222/can-i-inject-properties-from-maven-passwords-defined-in-settings-xml-into-my-s) about this issue, but these options didn't work for me.

I want to pass variables to app context:

```
<bean class="blah.blah.Blah" id="blah">
    <property name="first" value="${first.property}"/>
    <property name="second" value="${second.property}"/>
</bean>
```

I have the following in the Maven's `settings.xml` file:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profileId</id>
      <activation>
          <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
          <first.property>first value</first.property>
          <second.property>second value</second.property>
      </properties>
```

I tried [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10736501/1240930) (which is a bit strange), it gave no results. Than I added this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputFile>
            src/main/resources/maven.properties
          </outputFile>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And there wasn't any `maven.properties` files in the project afterwards. If I created empty file, nothing appeared in it. And I tried to do repeat these steps with `-PprofileId`, it didn't help. Could someone please provide a working code snippet or tell me what do I miss here? Thanks in advance.

**Update**: I was wrong, `properties-maven-plugin` works fine.

Comment: Where is your applicationContext.xml exactly, under `src/main/resources` or `src/main/java`?

Comment: @yorkw Under src/main/resources. Is it all right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your question - but if you tried running `mvn -PprofileId resources:resources` the properties plugin would not run, because the command is executing an individual goal, not a Maven lifecycle phase.  What happens if you run `mvn -PprofileId process-resources`?

Another question, are any other profiles active?  `activeByDefault` does not mean "always active."  Per [Maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) "All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config."  So if you have another profile active, the one with `profileId` will not be.

Try removing the activation block from that profile and run `mvn -PprofileId process-resources`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it didn't help, but made me recheck everything. Maven properties plugin works fine, I think you should write about that and I'll mark this answer. By the way, the problem was in the profiles, but in the other place. Also you are probably wrong about resources:resources, because it's the goal for the process-resources phase: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Correct, `resources:resources` is the goal bound to the process-resources phase.  There is a huge difference between running `mvn resources:resources` and `mvn process-resources`.  The first command executes the `resources:resources` goal and nothing else; it doesn't matter if there are goals bound to other phases, they will not be run.  The second command executes any goals bound to phases up to and including the `process-resources` phase.  The difference is subtle but very important. Try running both commands with `-X` and look at the execution plans, you'll see what I'm describing.