# How to acces POM project name from properties file

Tags: spring, maven, properties, spring-boot

I have `logback.properties` file which contains the following properties.

```
#logging
logging.server=
logging.port=
logging.path=/opt/${project.name}/logs
```

Inside my `POM` file I've got the `<name>` tag, which specifies the project name. I'd like to inject this name in few properties files like the `lockback` one above. Doing the above results in creating a folder called `project.name_IS_UNDEFINED`. Is it possible to access the project name and how?

**UPDATE**
Ralph gave the correct answer, however check my comment, because for spring boot applications you need to used `%project.name%` instead of `${project.name}`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107222/can-i-inject-properties-from-maven-passwords-defined-in-settings-xml-into-my-s

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo not quite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transfer the properties defined in you maven compile-time script into the application at run time.

The most easiest way is to use [maven's resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) (the name is a bit misleading, it is not a filter that selects files, it is a property replace for text/resource files) in order to let maven replace `${project.name}` in you logback.properties file.

true
        ${basedir}/src/main/resources

If you want enabling resource filtering just for one file (and not for the others to prevent maven from replacing other markers then you can use this snippet:

```
<resources>
    <!-- enable filtering for logback.properties only -->
    <resource>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>WHEREVER_LOCATED/logback.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>WHEREVER_LOCATED/logback.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ralph. Your answer helped me because I was missing the filtering :). However since I'm working on a spring boot application this did not fixed my problem fully. Instead I had to used %project.name% see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36501017/maven-resource-filtering-not-working-because-of-spring-boot-dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the resource filtering:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this same way like in application.properties using `@project.name@`

```
logging.path=/opt/@project.name@/logs
```